# Reverting rescaling an image

Tags: tensorflow

In order to train or test images in neural networks we often rescale an image to have zero mean and unit norm. TensorFlow does it by means of the function `tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)` (v.12).

However, in order to visualize an image, I believe I should revert it back to the original form. Am I correct? And if so, how we can revert the image?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just look at the original?

Comment: I am looking at the cifar10_input.py file from the official TensorFlow tutorial. I do not see how I can do it.